# Custom form element - widgets

Tags: adminhtml, forms, widgets

Is it possible to create a custom form element that can be used in widget instance creation?

Fields used in widgets is setup using widget.xml ,for example:

```
        <my_field>
            <label>My Field</label>
            <type>textarea</type>
        </my_field>
```

How can i replace textarea with a completely custom form element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is replace `textarea` with a block representing your new element.

```
<type>your_module/widget_new_element</type>
```

The you can create a class `Your_Module_Block_Widget_New_Element` that extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element`. Then depending on what you want your new element to do you can add customizations to this new block.